# "Migrate" command for manage.py not recognised when using Django 1.8

Tags: django, manage.py

Using "path/to/mySite/manage.py migrate" I get

```
Unknown command: 'migrate'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

Listed commands are:

```
changepassword
  cleanup
  compilemessages
  createcachetable
  createsuperuser
  dbshell
  diffsettings
  dumpdata
  flush
  inspectdb
  loaddata
  makemessages
  reset
  runfcgi
  runserver
  shell
  sql
  sqlall
  sqlclear
  sqlcustom
  sqlflush
  sqlindexes
  sqlinitialdata
  sqlreset
  sqlsequencereset
  startapp
  syncdb
  test
  testserver
  validate
```

I believe "Migrate" was added as a native command for manage.py as of Django 1.7.  According to "pip list" and the package documentation I am definitely using Django 1.8 and I explicitly called the correct versions of django-admin.py and manage.py in setup.

Comment: Look [HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/)

Comment: Hmm it should be there.  What does it say when you go ```./manage.py version```

Answer (score 0):

Run this

```
python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
```

This will tell you if you are being cockblocked by a different version of django either in this project's directory structure or somewhere in your PYTHONPATH